# Magento 2 Canonicals configuration

Tags: magento2

Good Morning.  I have a problem that I think is not derived from the canonicals because they are well configured but I do not know the reason for the problem​

I have it configured the canonicals in the following way. Use category path for redirects Urls of articles NO Use canonical link meta tags for Categories and Products YES

The problem that I see is if for example you enter a category like https://www.shopmami.com/productos-por-marcas/childhome/balancines-childhome and you open for example this article https: //www.shopmami. com / wooden-toys / balancin-infantil-scooter-childhome.html the url that shows is not https://www.shopmami.com/productos-por-marcas/childhome/balancines-childhome but that is https: / /www.shopmami.com/juguetes-de-madera/balancin-infantil-scooter-childhome.html

If you look for the product in Google and enter it you can see that the breacrumb shows instead the following category https://www.shopmami.com/productos-por-marcas/childhome/balancines-childhome
Someone could help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the canonical tag must (/should) be unique for a shop. So I guess with your settings magento picks out one category/product path to be the "right" one.

That's an unsolvable problem (with category paths included in product urls) since a product can be present in multiple categories.

From a seo perspective it would be better to disable category paths in product urls, since then you have a unique url for that product (baseurl/productpath) which will be present in the canonical.

The breadcrumb is a different concept. For Magento it's built from a User Experience Perspective, and will (in magento default) always show the path (including category path) from where you went to the product page (utilizing the referer).

So while the breadcrumb shows the complete category/product path, from where you accessed the product, the canonical link always points to the same (/unique) path.

Comment: Hello David.
Thank you very much for your reply. In our case it seems that we have two problems.
1 - I have a disable category path but in many products Magento 2.2.4 ignores it and shows the products with category path. I have installed Regenerate url rewrites of Olegkoval and when starting to regenerate the Urls automatically all of them generate a 404. Do you know how to solve the problem?
2 - Regarding the breadcrumbs the same thing happens to me, in some it shows well and in others only the name of the product, I imagine that the problem is of the template.